# Are there Application scope variables in Node js

Tags: node.js

I wanted to know are there any application scope variables that can be accessed anywhere in the whole application.

Since I want to add data to my HTML tags using javascript, I need to transfer/get data from the server.js to the index.html

Comment: The code you run using `node.js` does not communicate with the code you have in the web page. They run in different context, on different computers. `node.js` runs on the server; the code in the web page runs on the visitors' computers. The code you write for `node.js` **generates** the HTML page. All you have to do is to generate JavaScript code in `index.html`. The easiest way to do this is to use a template system, as suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

To transfer data from server.js to index.html you don't need to create global variables. You need to use a templating engine: [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html), [ejs](http://ejs.co/) or any other engine.

Just pass the data along with html file in the res.render() function and use templating syntax to display the data at the page.

**Router code:**

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!'});
});
```

**Pug code:**

```
html
  head
    title= title //Hey
  body
    h1= message //Hello there!
```

**ejs code:**

```
<html>
   <head> <%= title %> </head>
   <body>
       <h1> <%= message %> </h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey, i used ur method but i am getting an error - "Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided." (i installed npm ejs too)

Comment: Depending on the node.js framework you have to specify the templating engine. For express you can use:
 
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

In the app's main module.

Comment: Use express generator https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html.
Then create your app using the command "express --view=ejs myapp".